# Push Notifications to Windows Mobiles

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

Within my asp.net application I send push notifications to mobile phones. The user will have a client installed on their phone.

If they have android, I ask that they install NotifyMyAndroid on their phone.
If they have iOS I ask that they install Prowl on their phone.

What is the best option for Windows Mobiles?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Push notifications are part of the WP7 OS, read the MSDN article here:

[Push Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537%28VS.92%29.aspx)

Your end users do not need to install anything to make this work.